# Carry a double variable over from one method to another

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have a program to calculate tax payable on an income. The first method taxPayable() calculates the amount of tax that would be paid on this income and the second one incomeRemaining() should calculate the income remaining after the tax has been deducted but the variable tax is changing back to its first assignment of 0. How can i change my code so that it carries over to the next method?

```
public class TaxCalculator {
static double tax = 0;
public static void taxPayable(int income) {
    if (0 <= income && income <= 100) {
        double tax = 0;
        System.out.print("Tax payable on this income is equal to " + tax);
    }
    else if (101 <= income && income <= 150) {
        double tax = 0 + (income-100)*0.1;
        System.out.print("Tax payable on this income is equal to " + tax);
    }
    else if (151 <= income && income <= 200) {
        double tax = 0 + 50*0.1 + (income-150)*0.2;
        System.out.print("Tax payable on this income is equal to " + tax);
    }
    else if (201 <= income && income <= 300) {
        double tax = 0 + 50*0.1 + 50*0.2 + (income-200)*0.4;
        System.out.print("Tax payable on this income is equal to " + tax);
    }
    else if (301 <= income && income <= 400) {
        double tax = 0 + 50*0.1 + 50*0.2 + 100*0.4 + (income-300)*0.6;
        System.out.print("Tax payable on this income is equal to " + tax);
    }
    else {
        double tax = 0 + 50*0.1 + 50*0.2 + 100*0.4 + 100*0.6 + (income-400)*1.2;
        System.out.print("Tax payable on this income is equal to " + tax);
    }
}
public static void incomeRemaining(int income) {
    TaxCalculator.taxPayable(income);
    double $$ = income - tax;
    System.out.println("\nIncome remaining after tax is equal to " + $$);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TaxCalculator.incomeRemaining(400);
}
```

}

Comment: `double $$`, that doesn´t sound right.

Comment: Editing does not remove anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your **local** variable *tax* inside your method is **shadowing** the outer *static tax* variable.

So your code updates that "inner" tax; but not the outer.

Thus: simply remove all those

```
double tax = 0;
```

statements from the body of your method!

But: the **better** approach would be that your method *returns* that value. There is not much sense in using *global* variables to "communicate" values; when your method could simply return them! So change the method from "void" to "double", and simply return the computed value!

Plus: you duplicated those print statements for **no** reason. Just do **one** print in the end of the method! Seriously: whenever you have two pieces of code that do exactly the same thing ... get rid of the second one somehow!

And finally: never ever use special chars such as $ for variable/method/... names in your code!

Comment: I've done that but now it is giving me an error on the line:

Comment: double $$ = income - tax. saying that tax cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Honestly, go through a basic java tutorial, it will be a much better help than us telling you step to step how to resolve follow up mistakes after doing a tiny change.

Comment: Then you removed the **wrong** line! If you **do not** return a value, then have to keep the *global* static declaration of tax!

Comment: You are very welcome. But please consider yourself lucky. On another day, another audience might not have given you a quick answer, but quick downvotes and probably close requests. You see, this is really very basic stuff; and should try to work on such problems yourself intensively first. And for the record, I am lucky with upvotes here too.

Answer (score 1):

```
double $$ = income - tax;//here tax is using your class static variable tax, which is never changed from 0.
```

To debug.. change your class variable to 1000 instead of 0 as a default value.

In your taxPayable() method dont declare double tax again. Just use the variable without declaring it

Answer (score 0):

because you are re-declaring variable `tax` - please read about [scopes](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm). change each `double tax = ...` in your method `taxPayable(int income)` to just `tax`.